# "<Error>: doClip: empty path" - from webview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

See the image below (I sat a breakpoint on CGPostError). Is there anything to do with this error?? In console the following message was printed out: 
`<Error>: doClip: empty path`

We're building an iPad app and uses webkit to display custom ads.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for clipping functions with empty paths, like `CGContextClip()`.  In this case, the errors appears harmless and the "fix" appears equally harmless. From Apple's docs,

> **Parameters**
>   c
>   A graphics context that contains a path. If the context does not have a current path, the function does nothing.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html

If you really want to prevent logging the error, you should probably check the context before calling `CGContextClip(...)` or similar functions:

```
if (!CGContextIsPathEmpty(c))
{
    CGContextClip(c);
}
```